# use custom Formatter inside another custom formatter

Tags: json, scala

I implement my custom reads/writes formatter in order to serialize the class as json.

This question is continues question for: [Define different formatters for same class in the same trait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22812265/define-different-formatters-for-same-class-in-the-same-trait)

What i wish to do, I have a list of Product class in Tenant class, the formatter for tenant is not with implicit, it is a custom formatter.

```
val hsmTenantFormat = new Format[Tenant]
{
def writes(tenant: Tenant): JsValue = 
{
  val items = tenant.items.getOrElse(List[Product]())

  Json.obj(
    "items" -> tenant.items, //==> This line throw compile error since Product is not with implicit - cannot find formatter
    "prefixAndroid" -> tenant.prefixAndroid,
    "prefixIOS" -> tenant.prefixIOS,
    "er" -> tenant.er,
    "erMessage" -> tenant.erMessage
    )
}

def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Tenant] = 
{
  val items = (json \ "items").as[Option[List[Product]]]
  var itemsReal:Option[List[Product]] = None
  if (items.isDefined)
  {
      itemsReal = Some(items.get)
  }  
JsSuccess(new Tenant(
  itemsReal,
  (json \ "prefixAndroid").as[String],
  (json \ "prefixIOS").as[String],
  (json \ "er").as[Int], 
  (json \ "erMessage").as[String]
))
}
}}
```

This is working GOOD when Product is with implicit, but what happen when i wish to use customProductFormatter - a one that is not with implicit, i cant find where to set it.

Thanks!

This is my product formatter:

```
implicit val hsmProductFormat = new Format[Product] 
{
  def writes(item: Product): JsValue = 
  {
    val retailers = item.r.getOrElse(List[Retailer]())
    val images = item.images.getOrElse(List[String]())
    Json.obj(
      "u" -> item.u,
      "s" -> item.s,
      "z" -> item.z,
      "n" -> item.n,
      "v" -> item.v,
      "vu" -> item.vu,
      "t" -> item.t,
      "r" -> retailers,
      "images" -> images
    )
  }

  def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Product] = 
  {
    val retailers = (json \ "r").as[Option[List[Retailer]]]
    var retaliersReal:Option[List[Retailer]] = None
    if (retailers.isDefined)
    {
      retaliersReal = Some(retailers.get)
    }

    val images = (json \ "images").as[Option[List[String]]]
    var imagesReal:Option[List[String]] = None
    if (images.isDefined)
    {
      imagesReal = Some(images.get)
    }      
  JsSuccess(new Product(
    (json \ "u").as[String],
    (json \ "s").as[Int],
    (json \ "z").as[Int],
    (json \ "n").as[String],
    (json \ "v").as[String],
    (json \ "vu").as[String],
    (json \ "t").as[String],
    retailers,
    imagesReal
  ))
  }
}
```

I wish to remove the implicit from product format declaration, but if i do it, the compile cannot find formatter for Product !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I hope I understood your question well. I think there are two ways you can overcome this issue.

First one, declare an implicit format for `Product` in your Tenant's format so that it can "catch it up":

```
def writes(tenant: Tenant): JsValue = 
{
  val items = tenant.items.getOrElse(List[Product]())

  implicit val productWriter = Product.hsmProductFormat // <--- this should work

  Json.obj(
    "items" -> tenant.items, 
    "prefixAndroid" -> tenant.prefixAndroid,
    "prefixIOS" -> tenant.prefixIOS,
    "er" -> tenant.er,
    "erMessage" -> tenant.erMessage
    )
}
```

The second approach is to reference the needed writes directly:

```
def writes(tenant: Tenant): JsValue = 
{
  val items = tenant.items.getOrElse(List[Product]())

  Json.obj(
    "items" -> Product.hsmProductFormat.writes(tenant.items: _*), //as you have a List[Product] here, just add a ": _*" thing when calling writes
    "prefixAndroid" -> tenant.prefixAndroid,
    "prefixIOS" -> tenant.prefixIOS,
    "er" -> tenant.er,
    "erMessage" -> tenant.erMessage
    )
}
```

Cheers